# How to type constructor argument to initialise properties from plain object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to come up with a simple way to write a class with a constructor that takes a plain object argument, and initialises the instance properties accordingly.

```
class Foo {
  x: string
  y: string

  constructor(init: Foo) {
    Object.assign(this, init)
  }
}


new Foo({x: 'a', y: 'b'})
```

This gives an error on the two properties: "has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor". If `init` is a valid `Foo`, which the type system says it is, those properties *are* definitely assigned in the constructor. I realise that assertion relies on an understanding of `Object.assign`, but I've seen other examples where it seems the compiler does have that.

What would be the best way to fix this? Right now I'm adding initialisers, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: you can use `x!: string` to suppress this error, similarly for `y`.

Comment: If you are going to do this often or with a lot of properties you could make a little factory function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgJlm) which has a single type assertion in its implementation, and then you can use it like `class Foo extends ClassFor<{x: string, y: string}>() { /*..*/ }`.  If you are doing this infrequently and with few properties then definite assignment assertions like `x!: string; y!: string;` are the way to go.  If this meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what use cases are left unsatisfied.

Comment: Very nice @jcalz. I guess that approach is going to be slightly awkward if I *did* want to provide defaults, but otherwise, yes, it fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot perform the analysis on `Object.assign(this, init)` to know that all the properties of `this` will be initialized as a result.  The [typings for `Object.assign(target, ...args)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cec2fda9a53620dc545a2c4d7b0156446ab145b4/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L279-L313)  don't mutate the type of the `target` parameter at all.

You could use a [definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) for each and every property, to suppress the error:

```
class Foo {
  x!: string
  y!: string

  constructor(init: Foo) {
    Object.assign(this, init)
  }
}
```

and that's fine for a single `Foo` class with only two properties.  But it could be quite tedious indeed if you have lots of properties to initialize.

---

In such cases, you could write a class factory function which generalizes the pattern of copying the constructor parameter into `this`.  You only have to do a single [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation:

```
function ClassFor<T extends object>() {
  return class {
    constructor(init: any) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
    }
  } as new (init: T) => T;
}
```

And then you can just use the factory to generate your specific class constructors:

```
class Foo extends ClassFor<{ x: string, y: string }>() {

}
```

And verify that it behaves as you like:

```
const foo = new Foo({ x: 'a', y: 'b' })    
console.log(foo.x.toUpperCase()) // "A"
console.log(foo.y.toUpperCase()) // "B"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Cgkl4AbEKKJAMQHsa9CikAPAQgC4koAXTYLRkQCeHLrwz98g4jWA80AV3jcaaABQSM3TrRoBKBkyYoARgCsIygHTko2YGu4ALDFAA0STdz3SAvo38pImAIAHdqOjVcFk4AchBYjyE4k1ikXx9A0EhYBGQqBBU0IUMkADMFYGUMWSQAYTIKWjQAHgAVJAhmbghgABNKGnNLbgA+NQMCIzQIbgU0YGJGyimjGTleJSKNYC1OEGAhSekjUwtrW3tHF3dPXe8AbhP0vyRyJBDwnb2kNoMAXlGvyeRECjFItgi9C6PX6lAatmaLWizE48gkWCSaPE-HS42OASC6x45ToSH+HzCUKiMSQ8USSGSdNS6R84NkUBoJAgVhINCwajKdCszCsKgAqjAYBA0HVyBAJgYAPRKpAAIgAgmr2XIuTy+QKhTQrEIxTRJdLZfLFUgVeqAELa3xAA)